# in a binary search what is being 'returned'

Tags: java, recursion

```
   private static Comparable search(Comparable[] a, Comparable key, int left,
            int right) {
        while (left <= right) {
            int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
            if (key.compareTo(a[mid]) < 0) {                    
                return search(a, key, left, mid - 1);
            } else if (key.compareTo(a[mid]) > 0) {
                return search(a, key, mid + 1, right);
            } else {                        
                return a[mid];
            }
        }
        return "not found";

    }
```

I have a general understanding of algorithms and recursion but got confused at this point. If the first if statement runs 4 times, then what is being returned each of the 4 times? what would the actual value be? Is it going to be the same value for all of the stacks? which would be a[mid] for the base case

UPDATED CODE

edit :
My question is that each time "return" is called recursively, after I reach the base case and all the calls on the stack finish, what will their value be? If the first if statement runs twice, then it has 2 recursive calls on the stack waiting on a return value..what is that return value when the recursion finishes

Comment: This code is bad. Either the search must be recursive or use a loop.  This does both. Note neither `left` nor `right` are ever changed.  Therefore if the loop executes once, it executes forever.

Comment: The method doesn't seem correctly implemented (even though it might work): you're mixing an iterative implementation (there's a `while`) with a recursive implementation (the method is calling itself) of binary search - pick one and stick to it. See the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Recursive) for a comparison between both approaches

Comment: Why `else` when you `return`?

Comment: The code does appear "ok" (look at the return statements which is where the recursion occurs;  However I don't understand the question .. what "first statement" do you think is run 4 times and why?

Comment: @Gene ,The method seems fine to me , the op just used a while instead of an if ,its not doing loops or anything,after every while loop there will be always be a return ,so the loop breaks and there is not an infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will be the same value in all the parent calls.
Think it this way ,if a child call finds the Object then it will return it and the parent call will return what the child call returned ,next the parent call becomes the child of another parent call and the same happens .
Its hard to explain it in words but its just logic and the magic of recursion that our human brains are not used to it.

Comment: Ok thought so, I was just making sure that each call to 'return search(a, key, left, mid - 1);' will return the same value at one point

Answer (score 1):

So here is what the code is doing:

1. If still have values to check (the left index is less than or the same as the right index), the
2. Find the mid point
3. if the key is smaller than the value at the midpoint, call the search algorithm but with a reduced range (left to mid-1)
4. if the key is larger than the value at the midpoint, call the search algorithm but with a reduced range (mid+1 to right)
5. if the key is equal .. return the value
6. If the test at step 1 fails, then the key cannot be in the range, so return not found

The code runs ... what is your question.  Here is a full executable program, using your code (intact) as the search method.  The lines printed are `b` and `not found`
    public class BinSearch {

```
public BinSearch() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] info = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };
    String find = "b";
    String findToo = "x";

    System.out.println(search(info, find, 0, info.length - 1));
    System.out.println(search(info, findToo, 0, info.length - 1));
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private static Comparable search(Comparable[] a, Comparable key, int left,
        int right) {
    while (left <= right) {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        if (key.compareTo(a[mid]) < 0) {
            return search(a, key, left, mid - 1);
        } else if (key.compareTo(a[mid]) > 0) {
            return search(a, key, mid + 1, right);
        } else {
            return a[mid];
        }
    }
    return "not found";

}

}
```

Comment: Yes I know the code runs I tested it a few times, I am just wondering the logic behind the code. Basically what is being returned here "return search(a, key, left, mid - 1);". At this point the stack is on pause and another recursion starts, eventually the recursion stops and all the stacks must finish and have a return value correct? Basically the recursion is needed until you find a value or not found, that means all these calls must have the same return value? a[mid]? sorry if this is confusing

Answer (score 1):

What is being returned is the principle of a binary search, that is: if the key is smaller then a[mid], the outerbound (being right at that point) becomes the value mid. Basicly splitting the number of items in half and does that each time when the key is tested versus mid untill the while condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

*"My question is that each time "return" is called recursively, after I reach the base case and all the calls on the stack finish, what will their value be?*"

I've added debugging output. There's still a bug in your loop, but this should be informative towards figuring it out, and it should answer your question as well.

```
   import  java.util.Arrays;
/**
   <P>{@code java DebuggingRecursiveFunctionXmpl}</P>
 **/
public class DebuggingRecursiveFunctionXmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      Integer[] aiToSearch = new Integer[]{2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 10, 112};
      search(aiToSearch, 5);
      search(aiToSearch, 6);
      search(aiToSearch, -23);
      search(aiToSearch, 23223);
   }
   private static Comparable search(Comparable[] a, Comparable key) {
      return  search(a, key, 0, a.length);
   }
   private static Comparable search(Comparable[] a, Comparable key, int left, int right) {
      System.out.println("Searching for " + key + " in " + Arrays.toString(a) + ", from " + left + "-" + right);
      while (left <= right) {
         int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
         if (key.compareTo(a[mid]) < 0) {
            return search(a, key, left, mid - 1);
         } else if (key.compareTo(a[mid]) > 0) {
            return search(a, key, mid + 1, right);
         } else {
            System.out.println("Found at index " + mid);
            return a[mid];
         }
      }

        System.out.println("Not found. Returning -1");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\xbnjava]java DebuggingRecursiveFunctionXmpl
Searching for 5 in [2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 10, 112], from 0-9
Searching for 5 in [2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 10, 112], from 0-3
Searching for 5 in [2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 10, 112], from 2-3
Searching for 5 in [2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 10, 112], from 3-3
Found at index 3
Searching for 6 in [2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 10, 112], from 0-9
Found at index 4
Searching for -23 in [2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 10, 112], from 0-9
Searching for -23 in [2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 10, 112], from 0-3
Searching for -23 in [2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 10, 112], from 0-0
Searching for -23 in [2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 10, 112], from 0--1
Not found. Returning -1
Searching for 23223 in [2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 10, 112], from 0-9
Searching for 23223 in [2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 10, 112], from 5-9
Searching for 23223 in [2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 10, 112], from 8-9
Searching for 23223 in [2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 10, 112], from 9-9
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
        at DebuggingRecursiveFunctionXmpl.search(DebuggingRecursiveFunctionXmpl.java:22)
        at DebuggingRecursiveFunctionXmpl.search(DebuggingRecursiveFunctionXmpl.java:25)
        at DebuggingRecursiveFunctionXmpl.search(DebuggingRecursiveFunctionXmpl.java:25)
        at DebuggingRecursiveFunctionXmpl.search(DebuggingRecursiveFunctionXmpl.java:25)
        at DebuggingRecursiveFunctionXmpl.search(DebuggingRecursiveFunctionXmpl.java:16)
    at DebuggingRecursiveFunctionXmpl.main(DebuggingRecursiveFunctionXmpl.java:13)
```

Answer (score 1):

Trace it out and step back from the code. Look at it this way. Let's say you have an array like this:

```
inputList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

And you are looking for 6. You know the input source is sorted, so you can do a binary search.

A binary search should go to the middle element and look to see if the middle element is greater than or less than the target. If the target is greater than, you search recursively on a sublist of all greater than elements.  If it's less than you search on all elements that are less than the target.

Imagine this is our stack trace:

```
 return binary_search_on(inputList)
 ------------------------
 binary_search_on: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
      var middle = 4
      4 == 6? nope. 
         so, is 4 < 6? nope, crap. 
            bah! 4 > 6 ? yes.  return binary_search_on([5, 6, 7])
 ------------------------
 binary_search_on: [5,6,7]
      var middle = 6
      6 == 6? cool. return 6
```

So if you bubble back what does the recursive call return? It returns 6!  Replace anywhere you see `binary_search_on(...)` with the final returned value (6).

Lets follow the rest of it out:

```
 return binary_search_on(inputList)
 ------------------------
 binary_search_on: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
      var middle = 4
      4 == 6? nope. 
         so, is 4 < 6? nope, crap. 
            bah! 4 > 6 ? yes.  return 6
```

Here I replaced the call to `binary_search_on([5, 6, 7]) with 6 cause thats what it returns. Let's keep going:

```
 return 6
```

Well, the final return is 6, cause `binary_search_on[1,2,4,5,6,7]` also returns 6 now. And there we have it!

It may be confusing since you call "return" a bunch of times, but when the recursion finds the final result it will return the end result of the last recursive call.

Comment: Ty, I was having trouble verifying through debugging if the value was the same which is why I came here. "So if you bubble back what does the recursive call return? It returns 6! Replace anywhere you see binary_search_on(...) with the final returned value (6)" is what basically the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Nothing runs four times. The 'while' executes exactly once. If the body is executed, it returns something. The 'while' should be an 'if'.